# Integrating Twilio verfiy API with Dialogflow intent to ask for mobile number for OTP

Tags: node.js, twilio, dialogflow-es

I have made a working OTP Flow with Node.js and used the Verify API from Twilio for the SMS OTP. I tested it on Postman by adding and testing request everything from getting the OTP and verifying the OTP looks good.

Now I want to integrate this functionality in Dialogflow. I'm having problems doing it, and I cant seem to find any videos or documentation to help me. For just this phone number verification with a OTP for an intent that asks for the user's number. Then verifies that number after making the necessary API calls. I would like to ask for some help because i want to use this Twilio SMS verification functionality to verify phone numbers given through a chatbot. If you can refer me to some documentation or anything at all really that would help that will be fine. Thank you

This is just some part of the Node.js code I used to do this.

```js
const client = require("twilio")(config.accountSID, config.authToken)

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    client
          .verify
          .services(config.serviceID)
          .verifications
          .create({
              to: `+${req.query.phonenumber}`,
              channel: req.query.channel,
          })
          .then((data) => {
              res.status(200).send(data)
          })
})

app.get('/verify', (req,res) => {
    client
          .verify
          .services(config.serviceID)
          .verificationChecks
          .create({
            to: `+${req.query.phonenumber}`,
            code: req.query.code,
          })
          .then((data) => {
              res.status(200).send(data)
          })
})
```

Comment: What have you built so far with your Dialogflow agent?

Comment: A conversational form built with Dialogflow to basically collect user information. Like Fullname, email, phone number now I need to send an OTP to the phone number on input and I'm really not sure how to integrate that properly with Dialogflow. So I made one separately with node.js and the Twilio verify API tested both endpoints that are, send OTP and verify OTP endpoint on postman. Both work but I have no idea how to integrate this with Dialogflow and I can't seem to find any documentation or videos that can help. @philnash

Comment: I think you need need to look into [Dialogflow fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-overview). Rather than responding with static responses, fulfillment will allow you to set a URL to a service that Dialogflow will call with a webhook request and send the details of the conversation. You can then use that to trigger code, like sending or checking the verification.